How to set private file path with Migrate Upgrade
I am migrating a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 10. I've generated migrations using Migrate Upgrade:
drush migrate:upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=https://example.com --configure-only

I specified --legacy-root as a path to a copy of the D7 site on the filesystem and have been able to run the upgrade_d7_file migration task successfully. I have private files as well that need to be migrated. When I run the upgrade_d7_file_private migration task I get the following warning for each file:
[warning] is_file(): Unable to find the wrapper "private" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? FileSystem.php:317
[warning] unlink(): Unable to find the wrapper "private" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? FileSystem.php:118

The task completes and doesn't show as having failed, but no private files are present in the new site. There are no messages to view in the migration. After doing some searching it seems like you can manually provide or update the path for the private file migration, but I haven't been able to actually find out how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you set the private file path in the D10 site?

Thank you, no I hadn't set it. I updated settings.php with:
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/files/private';
That directory exists and is writeable by everyone (for migration purposes).
When I look at admin/config/media/file-system I do see the value there now under Private file system path.
Unfortunately the migration still has the same results as listed in the original post, same warnings and no files copied.

After setting the private file path and clearing caches I was able to run the private file migration successfully, thank you for your help.
